# How are the exclusions handled in RBAC design?

Tags: postgresql

Here is a scenario:

> `CLIENT_ONBOARDING_COMPLETED` attribute adds the ability to post jobs, send inquiries, etc. But if the user also belongs to the `BLOCKED_USER` group, we want to disable the ability to post a job, regardless of membership in other groups.

Behind the scenes, the hierarchy is:

- `feature`
- `user_group`
- `user_group_feature`
- `user_group_user_account`

As an example, there is a feature `POST_JOB`, which is associated with `CLIENT_ONBOARDING_COMPLETED`. The scenario describes user being added to a group `BLOCKED_USER`, which is meant to disable `POST_JOB`.

I am trying to conceptually understand how such a requirement is typically implemented.

Comment: What database version?  Are you running things in both mysql and postgres?

Comment: That was supposed to be "sql" and "postgresql" tags, but turns out "sql" is not a tag on dba.

Comment: In every production system I've encountered, permissions are either `GRANT` or `DENY` - for a given specific permission (e.g. `post-job`) then if a given User has both `GRANT` and `DENY` permissions then the `DENY` permission always takes precedence over any `GRANT` - this does mean that if you want to eventually allow something you'll need to find and delete all `DENY` permissions getting-in-the-way.